# Updating textbox in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, textbox

I have a problem with my matlab GUI, I don't use GUIDE, and I couldn't find a solution to my question elsewhere. The problem is that I have this one `textbox` and an `editbox`. When I change focus from the `editbox`, I want my `textbox` to get a new string, depending on what is in the `editbox`. With my current code I get no error message, but nothing happens.

Relevant part of my code:

```
nip_edit2=uicontrol('Parent', TabHandles{2,1}, ...    % edit2_nip         edit2
        'Position', [round(PanelWidth/4.5) 15.4*ButtonHeight ButtonHeight     ButtonHeight/2.5], ... 
        'String', '', ...
        'Style', 'edit', 'backgroundcolor','white',...
        'tag','edit2_nip_3',...
        'callback',@nip_passiv) ;
nip_edit3=uicontrol('Parent', TabHandles{2,1}, ...    % edit3_nip        text1
        'Position', [round(PanelWidth/4.5) 14.8*ButtonHeight ButtonHeight ButtonHeight/2.5], ...
        'String', '', ...
        'Style', 'text', 'backgroundcolor','white',...
        'tag','edit3_nip_3');  `

function nip_passiv (edit2_nip_3,edit3_nip_3)
A1=360-str2double(get(edit2_nip_3,'string'))
if A1<0
   errordlg('Angle 1 must be smaller than 360','Error');
   return
elseif A1> 360
   errordlg('Angle 1 must be bigger than 0','Error');
   return
end
set(edit3_nip_3,'string',A1)
drawnow
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'change focus'?

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where your code may break silently.

Firstly, `str2double` with an string that cannot be converted to numeric from decimal will return `NaN`, which means that all the subsequent operations (excepting tests like `isnan()`, `isfinite()` etc.) will return `NaN`. Also, all the comparisons with definite numbers will return `false`, which means that none of your `if`s will execute if the user enters, for example, `'abracadabra'`.

Secondly, the argument of the `set` function with `'String'` property should be a string, not a double. You'd be better with:

```
set(edit3_nip_3, 'String', num2str(A1));
```

**Later edit:**

Also, you should respect the callback style for an `uicontrol` as an Edit Text. [Here is the required list of arguments.](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html#f10-1001464) My advice is not to pass `edit3_nip_3` as argument (because the second argument is reserved to event data), but to save it at creation in your main GUI `handles` (as field in a struct, for example); the callback needs to be aware which handle is the destination of copying (so it would use the third argument to locate the `nip_edit3` value).

Comment: found my mistake! i didn't have them in the same function so it couldn't find the handles